# how can i include mustache js

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Ok so i added the type module and the error is gone but i still cant use Mustache, maybe i'm using it wrong i even tried to include it locally, so here you can see my code maybe you can help me with it, so without Mustache (working perfectly) :

The HTML side

```
      <h2>Mustache Test</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sint pariatur soluta nemo odit dolor ipsum laboriosam dolore ullam rerum commodi, vitae culpa totam autem praesentium, iste eveniet accusantium nam?</p>
    <ul id="someData"></ul>
```

Javascript side :

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/displayAllUsers",
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, user) {
      $("#someData").append('<li> name: '+ user.name +' </li>');
    });
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Fail");
  },
});
```

so this is working perfectly :
[results without Mustache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC49w.png)

But i want to work with Mustache because i will need more complicated template in the future so here's what i tried:

Html Side:

```
        <ul id="someData">
      <template id ="user-template">
        <li>
          <p>
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            <span>{{name}}</span>
          </p>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
```

Javascript side:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

var userTemplate = $("user-template").html();

function displayUsers(user){
  $("#someData").append(Mustache.render(userTemplate, user));
}


$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/displayAllUsers",
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, user) {
      displayUsers(user);
    });
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Fail");
  },
});
```

});

So i dont think I am wrong here, because in my browser console it saying that Mustache is not defined, here is the error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFz0Y.png)

and here you can see that nothing is displayed:

[data displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFhlr.png)

Comment: It's a new ecosystem, and you can use it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tvpjL4ck/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are trying to load contains an [ECMAScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

To use it you need to rewrite your code so that it is also a module.

Essentially that means moving your code into a script element with `type="module"`.

```
<script src="/js/mymodule.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then, inside your top level module you can load dependencies using the [`import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

```
import mustache from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/4.2.0/mustache.min.js"

/* mustache is now a variable with the value imported from the module */

const view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

const output = mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);

console.log(output);
```

You can also inline it. Live demo under the fold.

```html
<script type="module">
    import mustache from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/4.2.0/mustache.min.js"

    const view = {
      title: "Joe",
      calc: function () {
        return 2 + 4;
      }
    };
   
    const output = mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);

    console.log(output);
</script>
```

Comment: Iam Sorry iam a beginner in web developpement i didnt understand where should i put the import of moustache i only have an index.html

Comment: You see where in the question you said "Javascript side"?

Comment: like that ? `<script type="module">
  import mustache from "mustache.js"

  $(document).ready(function () {

var userTemplate = $("user-template").html();

function displayUsers(user){
  $("#someData").append(Mustache.render(userTemplate, user));
}


$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/displayAllUsers",
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, user) {
      displayUsers(user);
    });
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Fail");
  },
});
});
</script>`

Comment: Yes, like that..

Comment: hmm, i guess its working no error but my var userTemplate = $("user-template").html(); is returning undefined

Comment: Well, there's no `<user-template>` element in the HTML spec.

Comment: omg i forgot the # before user-template , sorry for wasting your time, its working perfectly thank you!